# Checking a Maven POM for tabs

Tags: xml, maven

I have bunsch of Maven projects and we have the problem that some people uses tabs for indenting the content of the file.

Is there a tool that integrates nicely with Maven to check the POM for tabs?

Comment: This has nothing to do with maven. Maven doesn't care how the XML is formatted, so long as it's valid. If you don't like tabs, use any tool you like to get rid of them. I like `sed`.

Comment: I would suggest to take a look here: https://github.com/Ekryd/sortpom/wiki